# Jest typescript tests runs twice, one for ts files, and one for js files

Tags: typescript, jestjs

I'm starting to write some tests using Jest and typescript, however I'm getting some errors and the problem seems to be that the tests are run twice, one for ts files, and a second time for js files.

The typescript test passes, but the compiled javascript tests don't.

```
yarn run v1.5.1
$ jest
 PASS  src/__tests__/some.test.ts (7.955s)
  ● Console

    console.log src/lib/google-analytics/ga-api.ts:75
      Succsess!!
    console.log src/__tests__/some.test.ts:42
      { reports: { batchGet: [Function: batchGet] } }

 FAIL  dist/__tests__/some.test.js
  ● Console

    console.log dist/lib/google-analytics/ga-api.js:64
      Reject

  ● it gets a full google analytics report

    No key or keyFile set.

      68 |
      69 |         return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    > 70 |             jwtClient.authorize((err: any) => {
      71 |                 if (err) {
      72 |                     console.log("Reject");
      73 |                     reject(err);

      at GoogleToken.<anonymous> (node_modules/googleapis/node_modules/gtoken/src/index.ts:102:13)
      at step (node_modules/googleapis/node_modules/gtoken/build/src/index.js:42:23)
      at Object.next (node_modules/googleapis/node_modules/gtoken/build/src/index.js:23:53)
      at node_modules/googleapis/node_modules/gtoken/build/src/index.js:17:71
      at Object.<anonymous>.__awaiter (node_modules/googleapis/node_modules/gtoken/build/src/index.js:13:12)
      at GoogleToken.Object.<anonymous>.GoogleToken.getTokenAsync (node_modules/googleapis/node_modules/gtoken/build/src/index.js:102:16)
      at GoogleToken.Object.<anonymous>.GoogleToken.getToken (node_modules/googleapis/node_modules/gtoken/src/index.ts:93:17)
      at JWT.<anonymous> (node_modules/googleapis/node_modules/google-auth-library/src/auth/jwtclient.ts:181:37)
      at step (node_modules/googleapis/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/jwtclient.js:57:23)
      at Object.next (node_modules/googleapis/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/jwtclient.js:38:53)
      at node_modules/googleapis/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/jwtclient.js:32:71
      at Object.<anonymous>.__awaiter (node_modules/googleapis/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/jwtclient.js:28:12)
      at JWT.Object.<anonymous>.JWT.refreshToken (node_modules/googleapis/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/jwtclient.js:181:16)
      at JWT.<anonymous> (node_modules/googleapis/node_modules/google-auth-library/src/auth/jwtclient.ts:154:31)
      at step (node_modules/googleapis/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/jwtclient.js:57:23)
      at Object.next (node_modules/googleapis/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/jwtclient.js:38:53)
      at node_modules/googleapis/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/jwtclient.js:32:71
      at Object.<anonymous>.__awaiter (node_modules/googleapis/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/jwtclient.js:28:12)
      at JWT.Object.<anonymous>.JWT.authorizeAsync (node_modules/googleapis/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/jwtclient.js:156:16)
      at JWT.Object.<anonymous>.JWT.authorize (node_modules/googleapis/node_modules/google-auth-library/src/auth/jwtclient.ts:147:12)
      at Promise (src/lib/google-analytics/ga-api.ts:70:23)
      at GoogleAnalyticsApiClient.getGCPAuthToken (src/lib/google-analytics/ga-api.ts:69:16)
      at GoogleAnalyticsApiClient.<anonymous> (src/lib/google-analytics/ga-api.ts:52:42)
      at dist/lib/google-analytics/ga-api.js:7:71
      at Object.<anonymous>.__awaiter (dist/lib/google-analytics/ga-api.js:3:12)
      at GoogleAnalyticsApiClient.getGaApiClient (dist/lib/google-analytics/ga-api.js:50:16)
      at Object.<anonymous>.test (src/__tests__/some.test.ts:41:14)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 passed, 2 total
Tests:       1 failed, 1 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        9.516s
Ran all test suites.
error An unexpected error occurred: "Command failed.
Exit code: 1
Command: sh
Arguments: -c jest
Directory: /Users/carlosbernal/Documents/Grability/DataScience/ga-downloader
Output:
".
info If you think this is a bug, please open a bug report with the information provided in "/Users/carlosbernal/Documents/Grability/DataScience/ga-downloader/yarn-error.log".
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

Is this normal in ts-jest or am I missing some extra configuration?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

> Is this normal in ts-jest or am I missing some extra configuration

You should set `roots` to `/src` only. [Here is a good config](https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/intro-1/jest#step-2-configure-jest):

```
module.exports = {
  "roots": [
    "<rootDir>/src"
  ],
  "transform": {
    "^.+\\.tsx?$": "ts-jest"
  },
  "testRegex": "(/__tests__/.*|(\\.|/)(test|spec))\\.tsx?$",
  "moduleFileExtensions": [
    "ts",
    "tsx",
    "json"
  ],
}
```

I also only test `.tsx?` files (no `.jsx?`) ;)

Comment: This doesn't work in my setup, because I'm using jest snapshot serializers written in TypeScript. :( I think removing `/jsx?/` from `moduleFileExtensions` would fix this, but currently it triggers this bug: https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/4025

Comment: Awesome, thanks. The line with `moduleFileExtensions` was what I needed in my case. Without it, jest will prefer to import my `*.js` files and run tests against them instead. If i include it, jest switches to use the desired behavior where it gives priority to the files with the `*.ts` extension instead.

Comment: I found just the "roots" fixed my problem where Jest was also running the compiled js files in a `lib` output folder next to `src`. However if I tried setting `moduleFileExtensions` to just ["ts"] Jest would complain saying it must include "js"!

Answer (score 17):

Had the same issue, using the aws cdk in Typescript, to prevent it, I added `.js` to the testPathIgnorePatterns property in jest-config.js

```
module.exports = {
  preset: 'ts-jest',
  testEnvironment: 'node',
  testPathIgnorePatterns: [".d.ts", ".js"]
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If using IDE, you just might want to disable the `.ts` to `.js` compilation that occurs in those IDEs to avoid generating that `.js` file giving you the issues.

For IntelliJ/Webstorm users:  See Preferences | Languages & Frameworks | TypeScript, Recompile on changes (uncheck)